# Is Competition Problem on Constrained Inequality Relevant in Research?

Tags: inequality, soft-question, contest-math, problem-solving, research

Many inequality problems on variable $x,y,z$ or $a, b$ come with constraints such as $ab = 1,xyz = 1, x+y+z = 1$. For example, Let $a$ and $b$ be positive real numbers with $a + b = 1$ then prove that - $$ \frac{a^2}{a + 1}+ \frac{b^2}{b + 1} ≥\frac1 3$$  (Hungary 1996).

Now I understand that contest-problem is good for exercise but what I am asking, is that are such inequality are useful in research? Or are such inequality found in research level mathematics?

This question is motivated [by this post (click here).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234970/how-is-problem-solving-ability-on-an-olympiad-level-relevant-to-mathematical-gra)

Comment: how are $a,b$ related to $x,y,z$?

Comment: They do appear in research, esp in analysis when you want to bound stuff. E.g. The discrete form of holders is used in olympiads, and the continuous form is used in several analysis proofs.

Comment: On the one hand, these inequality questions are meant to test ability to apply, adapt, think creatively, etc. However, it is now well understood that such "contrived" inequalities can often be brute-force bashed, which makes them less desirable as an olympiad problem. E.g. If I'm right, the IMO hasn't used an explicit inequality since 2005.

Comment: @CalvinLin Nice comments!! could u plz post answer with a reference/mention of application of such inequities in research.

Comment: @Andrei they are not , i was giving examples...

Comment: @Calvin Lin You not right. In IMO an inequality was in $2012$. See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3839_2012_imo Also, I absolutely don't agree with you. Methods about which you say it's impossible to use in IMO because we need to solve problems by "pencil and paper". Also, we always see inequalities in national contexts. Also, your words, we really can say about geometry in IMO  and functional equations in IMO, but not about inequalities.

Comment: So, looking at the past 25 years of IMO, the inequality questions are 12/2, 06/3, 05/3, 03/5, 01/2, 00/2, 99/2, 97/3(?), 95/2. That supports my POV that in recent (past 10) years , the IMO has greatly reduced usage of explicit inequality questions. Of course, there could be many reasons for that, like having a greater variety of questions to choose from. I agree that we still see inequalities in national contests, in part because that's easy for people to gravitate towards. As a clarification, I'm a fan of inequality questions. (In fact, contest-math and inequalities are my watched tags)

Answer (score 1):

Such problems are very useful in research, particularly when we want to optimize some property of a system under constraints.  This occurs when we're designing computer chips (optimize bandwidth consistent with power envelope), internal-combustion motors (optimize power consistent with fuel economy standards), finance (optimize return on investment consistent with portfolio or legal constraints), etc.

Answer (score -1):

By C-S we obtain: $$\frac{a^2}{a+1}+\frac{b^2}{b+1}\geq\frac{(a+b)^2}{a+1+b+1}=\frac{1}{3}.$$
Now we see that $\frac{1}{3}$ is a minimal value of the function $f(a,b)=\frac{a^2}{a+1}+\frac{b^2}{b+1}$

under conditions $a>0$, $b>0$ and $a+b=1$ (because the equality occurs for $a=b=\frac{1}{2}$).

Id est, we solved an optimization problem without standard Lagrange Multipliers method.

Specific this inequality is very easy, but of course  it can be found in research level mathematics.

Comment: +1 , but what I am asking, is that are such inequality are useful in research? Or are such inequality found in research level mathematics? Would u plz comment on this?

Comment: @Andrew I added something two weeks ago.